# Git submodules fails on TFS Build using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, tfs, tfsbuild, git-submodules

So I have a project on TFS and I'm trying to set up continuous integration by using a build definition.My project has several git submodules that are also on TFS but in a different project.

When creating the build definition I run into the issue where fetching the git submodule fails because the submodules uses SSH instead of https.

The exact error is 
Host key verification failed.
Could not read from remote repository.

Using https fixes the error however my boss insists on using SSH.

Any suggestions/advice on how I can do this?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Answer (score 0):

> Host key verification failed.

That means the `~/.known_hosts` file is not properly filled out.
If you can, try on the TFS server an `ssh user@server` and answer 'yes': that will update the `known_hosts`.

Then you can go back on the client side, and the build definition should be able to access those URLs.

Comment: How would I access the TFS server?

Comment: Then you need to contact the TFS administrator.